# ConvNet: Not getting the required output in the max pooling function

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement CNN using only numpy. I am getting the error of index out of bound in the max pooling layer.

The function takes the feature map array as the argument. Feature map array is an ndarray. Here is my function:

```
feature_map = np.array([[[4, 3, 4],[2, 4, 3],[2, 3, 4]],
          [[3, 4, 2],[2, 4, 4],[2, 4, 2]],
          [[5, 7, 6],[2, 1, 3],[3, 3, 8]],    
          [[3, 3, 2],[1, 3, 5],[7, 4, 9,]]])

def pool_forward(feature_map, mode = "max", size=2, stride=2):

    f_num, f_row, f_col = feature_map.shape
    #Preparing the output of the pooling operation.
    pool_out = np.zeros((np.uint16((f_row-size+1)/stride+1),
                        np.uint16((f_col-size+1)/stride+1), f_num))

    for map_num in range(f_num):
        r2 = 0
        for r in np.arange(0,f_row-size+1, stride):
            c2 = 0
            for c in np.arange(0, f_col-size+1, stride):
                pool_out[r2, c2, map_num] = np.max([feature_map[r:r+size,  
                                            c:c+size, map_num]])
                c2 = c2 + 1
            r2 = r2 +1

    return np.array(pool_res)
```

This is the error I get:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-ccb65cb3a606> in <module>()
----> 1 feature_pool = pool_forward(features)
  2 feature_pool.shape

<ipython-input-102-5d4c4e76f99a> in pool_forward(feature_map, mode, 
filter_size, stride)
 13             c2 = 0
 14             for c in np.arange(0, f_col-filter_size+1, stride):
 ---> 15                 pool_out[r2, c2, map_num] = 
 np.max([feature_map[r:r+filter_size,  c:c+filter_size, map_num]])
 16                 c2 = c2 + 1
 17             r2 = r2 +1

IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 2 with size 3
```

Help me out here.

Comment: It would be useful to explain your pool_forward function and what your output should be.

Comment: pool_forward is the max pooling function applied on the feature maps obtained after the convolution in a Convolutional Neural Network. The output should be 4 2x2 arrays for each of the four feature maps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please check the update part of the answer:**

The error lies in the line:

```
pool_out[r2, c2, map_num] = np.max([feature_map[r:r+size, c:c+size, map_num]])
```

It should be:

```
pool_out[r2, c2, map_num] = np.max([feature_map[map_num, r:r+size, c:c+size]])
```

Now:

```
def pool_forward(feature_map, mode = "max", size=2, stride=2):

    f_num, f_row, f_col = feature_map.shape
    #Preparing the output of the pooling operation.
    pool_out = np.zeros((np.uint16((f_row-size+1)/stride+1),
                        np.uint16((f_col-size+1)/stride+1), f_num))

    for map_num in range(f_num):
        r2 = 0
        for r in np.arange(0,f_row-size+1, stride):
            c2 = 0
            for c in np.arange(0, f_col-size+1, stride):
                pool_out[r2, c2, map_num] = np.max([feature_map[map_num, r:r+size, c:c+size]])
                c2 = c2 + 1
            r2 = r2 +1

    return np.array(pool_res)



feature_map = np.array([[[4, 3, 4],[2, 4, 3],[2, 3, 4]],
          [[3, 4, 2],[2, 4, 4],[2, 4, 2]],
          [[5, 7, 6],[2, 1, 3],[3, 3, 8]],    
          [[3, 3, 2],[1, 3, 5],[7, 4, 9,]]])

pool_forward(feature_map)
```

returns:

```
array([[[4., 4., 7., 3.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.]]])
```

**Update**: The premise of the question is incorrect. With an input of shape 3*3 You have a pooling window-size of 2*2 and a stride of 2 then you might want to look into `fractional_max_pooling`. For regular `max_pooling` you should choose a stride of 1.(ie the value `(f_row-size)/stride` should be an integer). In this case check out the code below:

```
feature_map = np.array([[[4, 3, 4],[2, 4, 3],[2, 3, 4]],
          [[3, 4, 2],[2, 4, 4],[2, 4, 2]],
          [[5, 7, 6],[2, 1, 3],[3, 3, 8]],    
          [[3, 3, 2],[1, 3, 5],[7, 4, 9,]]])

def pool_forward(feature_map, mode = "max", size=2, stride=1):
    f_num, f_row, f_col = feature_map.shape
    pool_out = np.zeros((f_num,np.uint16((f_row-size)/stride+1),\
                     np.uint16((f_col-size)/stride+1)))
    for z in range(f_num):
        for r in np.arange(0,f_row-size+1, stride):
            for c in np.arange(0, f_col-size+1, stride):
                pool_out[z, r, c] = np.max(feature_map[z, r:r+size, c:c+size])
    return pool_out
```

`pool_forward(feature_map)` returns:

```
array([[[4., 4.],
        [4., 4.]],

       [[4., 4.],
        [4., 4.]],

       [[7., 7.],
        [3., 8.]],

       [[3., 5.],
        [7., 9.]]])
```

This seems to be correct. Also I tossed variables c2 and r2 because they dont seem to be necessary.

Comment: but the required output should be 4 2x2 arrays for each of the four 3x3 feature map arrays

Comment: How do you propose to pool 3*3 tensor into 2*2 tensors (with a stride of 2) ? Your premiseis first of all wrong. You should chose a stride of 1 to pool 3*3 into 2*2. Please draw it down and check it out.

Comment: thank you for understanding and replying to my question though it wasn't conveyed properly